# Replace string with special characters using perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl, special-characters

I'm trying to replace a string like

```
</string§>
```

with

```
new string line 1
new string line 2
```

with perl on Linux.

The problem is, that it won't accept the < and > as well as the /.

This is what i got:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\<\/string§\>/new string line 1 \n new string line 2/se' file.xml
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Backslash escapes on one-liners can be entertaining.  You've got to get the backslash past your shell before Perl can see it.  anubhava has the right idea of entirely avoiding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `s` and `e` modifiers and can also use an alternate regex demiter (other than `/`) to avoid escaping:

```
perl -pe 's~</string§>~new string line 1 \nnew string line 2~' file.xml
new string line 1
new string line 2
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Another question: do you know a good perl tutorial?

Comment: @JakobBenz, your substitution would have worked well in a perl script.  You ran afoul of your shell.